# How to prevent users from sending email without logging in?

Tags: postfix

Currently, anyone with telnet can send an email to `recipient@example.com` using a spoofed address of `sender@example.com`. I want to prevent this.

I have the following in postfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks
   permit_sasl_authenticated
   reject_sender_login_mismatch
   reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch
   reject_unauth_destination
   reject_known_sender_login_mismatch
   check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
```

None of this works. I want to require a user to have to type in their user name and password if they are sending an email to another user on the same domain.

Looking at http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html in the "Envelope sender address authorization" section, they have you set up an alias table. But I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: `permit_mynetworks` is documented in `man 5 postconf`. Before you make any changes, carefully investigate whether you have services running on your system which you want to send mail without logging in (such as `cron`, `mdadm`).

Comment: OK, thanks. I put "@example.com @example.com" into the controlled_envelope_senders file and that did the trick but didn't think about whether cron or other services send email. Users could be using cell phones to send email so I'm not sure how permit_networks would work. That's something I have in my config by default. Should I just take it out?